# Approximating the $U(1)$ Schwinger model with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, quantum-electrodynamics, lattice-model

The Schwinger model or $(\text{QED})_2$ essentially is quantum electrodynamics defined in $1 + 1$ spacetime dimensions. In https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02361 they use the Hamiltonian formulation to represent the Schwinger model on the lattice and use a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ approximation of the $U(1)$ symmetry.

After doing some research I was unable to get a proper understanding how to employ this $\mathbb{Z}_2$ approximation.

Specifically I would like to understand:

1. How to see that the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry is still intact while the $U(1)$ symmetry is no more?
2. Starting from the $U(1)$ symmetric theory as it is presented in https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.1043, how does one arrive at the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ Hamiltonian?

It might as well be that I still have some misconceptions, in which case I would be very happy if these could be clarified.

Thanks!

Comment: The Schwinger model is specifically *massless* $(1+1)$-dimensional QED.

Comment: There is no immediate relation between $U(1)$ gauge theory and $\mathbb Z_2$ gauge theory. The latter is simpler to implement on the lattice, this is why the authors chose it. One can connect the two theories via an RG flow (say, with a Higgs) but this is quite orthogonal to the point of that paper.

Comment: Okay, but then I don't understand the statement “In this work, we simulate $1 + 1d$ $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory with a single massive fermion, which is the simplest discrete subgroup approximation of the Schwinger model.”

To me it suggests there would be a specific approximation that can be applied to go to their model. The subgroup relation is clear, but why this is a suitable approximation or how the details work out.

Comment: @rgba The details do not work out, and the authors of the paper do not claim that they do. $\mathbb Z_2$ is the simplest subgroup of $U(1)$, but $\mathbb Z_2$ gauge theory is *not* a "subgroup" of $U(1)$ gauge theory. These two theories have a very different spectrum (although coincidentally they have a similar phase diagram, they both have a single critical point described by the Ising CFT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_2$ gauge theory and $U(1)$ gauge theory are not related in any quantitative way. The former is an "intuitive" approximation to the latter only to the extent that both are gauge theories, and the former is simpler to work with. This is a qualitative statement: you can study gauge dynamics in both theories, such as confinement, but $\mathbb Z_2$ will always be easier to work with, so it provides a nice "model" for $U(1)$. There is no parameter in $U(1)$ that, when small, it reduces to $\mathbb Z_2$. (Of course one can connect both theories via an RG flow by adding, say, a charge-2 heavy boson; this is not a particularly deep statement and doesn't really buy us anything here).

To be very explicit, in $d=1+1$, both $\mathbb Z_2$ and $U(1)$ gauge theories are very well understood. For example, $U(1)$ gives rise to a dynamically generated mass scale: the massless photon of $U(1)$ combines with the massless fermion, and they form a composite *massive* boson with mass $m_\phi\sim e$. This boson is the famous "Coleman scalar". The same phenomenon does *not* occur in $\mathbb Z_2$: here the fermion stays massless. Gauge dynamics in the case of $U(1)$ are rich enough to open up a quantum-mechanical gap, while the dynamics of $\mathbb Z_2$ are much more boring and they do not open up a gap. So hopefully this is evidence enough to convince you that the two theories are not, in any sense, approximately similar.

There is no way to arrive at the $\mathbb Z_2$ theory by taking the $U(1)$ theory other than, say, by artificially adding the aforementioned charge-2 scalar. But this is not something that will "simplify" the calculation, it will only add layers of complexity, so it is not something you want to do if $\mathbb Z_2$ is what you are after. You may just as well construct $\mathbb Z_2$ directly, without ever mentioning the $U(1)$ theory. To this end you just follow the standard route: you write down the Hamiltonian of a single fermion (which you already know how to do: it is the same as in the $U(1)$ case) and gauge the $\mathbb Z_2$ symmetry by adding Pauli matrices on the edges, as is standard in, say, the Ising chain. The end result is, of course, the Hamiltonian they write in the reference in the OP.

Comment: To be clear: $\mathbb Z_n$ gauge theory is simpler than $U(1)$ gauge theory because the former has finite dimensional local Hilbert spaces while the latter has infinite-dimensional local Hilbert spaces. It should be obvious why it is much easier to put finite-dimensional stuff on the lattice.

Comment: I understand the theories are not the same in the sense of making approximated predictions. What I was wondering about is, how they can be systematically derived, e. g. by simply using the fact that they are subgroups. I also read somewhere that in the limit of $n$ going to infinity, $U(1)$ is recovered.